# How can I read multiple csv file from different sub directories and find the csv file which has the value?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have a root directory(folder) `z` and `i` have three sub-directory(folders) `a, b,` and `c`

Each `a, b,` and `c` contain one `csv` file which are similar data and have similar names `a_data, b_data,` and `c_data)`

Out of three `csv` files, only one `csv` contains the value of integer `100` inside data frame.``

How can I design a loop that scans all `csv` inside three sub-folders and tells me which `csv` has the value "100"?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Include your code showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
val = 100
subdir_files = glob.glob(folder_path  + '/**/*.csv', recursive=True)
for file in subdir_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    if val in df['column_name'].values:
        print(file)
        break
```

Comment: Might want to add a break to avoid looping after you've found the file. It may also be helpful to include a flag for if anything was found

Comment: Thanks for your answer. from 7th line of your code, What if I want to find value of 100 anywhere regardless of column name? Is it okay if I do df.values?

Comment: @JunyoungBae That would also be okay

Comment: @Mohnish Quick question. How can I change the code of glob.glob if I have other csv files that I do not want to include for df? for example, I only want to include a_data, b_data not other data

Comment: @JunyoungBae you can add `if file.split("/")[-2] == file.split("/")[-1].replace('_data.csv',""):` after for loop and the rest of the code inside this. that would check if file name 'a_data.csv' is in folder 'a'

Comment: @Mohnish thanks. I tried your code, but somehow it only reads one df from file and only saves one df. Do you have any idea why it behaves likes this? The saved data doesn't even include value of 100

Comment: @JunyoungBae i tired using it in my folder with structure  Folder  |   a -> a_data.csv, file.csv  b -> b_data.csv, a_data.csv  c -> a_data.csv,c_ data.csv   The full code is        `subdir_files = glob.glob(folder_path  + '/**/*.csv', recursive=True)  
    for file in subdir:  
        if file.split("/")[-2] == file.split("/")[-1].replace('_data.csv',""):  
            df = pd.read_csv(file)  if val in df.values:
      print(file)`

Answer (score 1):

I can't profile my idea at the moment, but I assume it is going to be faster to open each file with Pandas than try to search through the text of the CSV before opening it in Pandas. Also, it will probably read better.

So, under the assumption that its faster to open everything with Pandas than using something like the [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), let's do:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("~/z/a/a_data.csv")

if not df["column"].isin([100]).all():
  df = pd.read_csv("~/z/b/b_data.csv")

  if not df["column"].isin([100]).all():
    df = pd.read_csv("~/z/c/c_data.csv")

    if not df["column"].isin([100]).all():
      print("No value")
```

Ultimately, nested if's aren't pretty. But, it's hard to find what's the right fit without seeing your code. If you can post your code, that would help. Otherwise, hope the above helps you get started.

Comment: I have tried this way before, however the problem is that what if i have more than three sub folders? Wouldn't it be cleaner to use loop to find csv in each data? I can't really think of loop that well

Comment: @JunyoungBae Correct, at some point you definitely don't want nested if's. You'd probably want something recursive and/or one where it leverages `os`. So you'd end up with something that looks at the folder structure and checks through each csv opening it with pandas like `df = pd.read_csv(root_folder_str + "/" + sub_folder_str + "/" + file_name_str)`. If you need more help, edit your question to be your exact project structure and I will edit my answer based on that. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your `csv_files` list like this, reading each using `pandas.read_csv` and finding the first one with the desired value. The `else` clause of the `for` loop will be executed if the loop ended normally (i.e. not on `break`), corresponding to none of the files containing the desired value.

```
import pandas as pd
csv_files = ["a/a.csv", "b/b.csv", "c/c.csv"]
found_df = None
for csv_file in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    if 100 in df["column"].values:
        found_df = df
        break
else:
    print("No value found")
```